# Erro ao tentar buscar dados

Tags: android, sqlite

Tenho uma aplicação que deve inserir dados em uma tela e na outra consultar no banco

O problema é que sempre que tento executar a consulta da erro:

**Log**

```
11-16 18:43:31.023: I/ActivityManager(26887): Timeline: Activity_launch_request     id:br.com.exercicio8 time:58351239
11-16 18:43:31.103: D/AndroidRuntime(26887): Shutting down VM
11-16 18:43:31.103: W/dalvikvm(26887): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught    exception (group=0x41996d88)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887): Process: br.com.exercicio8, PID: 26887
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.exercicio8/br.com.exercicio8.LocalizacaoAtual}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2237)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2286)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887): Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at br.com.exercicio8.LocalizacaoAtual.onLocationChanged(LocalizacaoAtual.java:85)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at br.com.exercicio8.LocalizacaoAtual.onCreate(LocalizacaoAtual.java:46)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2201)
11-16 18:43:31.103: E/AndroidRuntime(26887):    ... 11 more
```

**Código que é executado do SQLiteOpenHelper**

```
public Cursor consult(int latiude, int longitude){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "select "+CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL+" from " + LOCATION_TABLE_NAME + " where + " + CADASTRO_COLUMN_LATITUDE + " = " + latiude + " AND "+ CADASTRO_COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " = " +longitude;
            Cursor registro = db.rawQuery(query, null); //objeto do sqllite que representa um objeto de qualquer tabela
            return registro;
       }
```

**Código na classe**

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    double lat = location.getLatitude();
    double lon = location.getLongitude();
    campoLat = (int)lat;
    campoLong = (int)lon;

    BD dbm = new BD(getApplicationContext());
    Cursor seleciona = dbm.consult(campoLat,campoLong);
    seleciona.moveToFirst();
    String aux = seleciona.getString(seleciona.getColumnIndex(BD.CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL));
    /*
    if(aux != "" || aux != null)
    {
        local.setText(aux);
    }
    else
    {
        local.setText("Local desconhecido");
    }*/
```

**Codigo do banco**

```
 public class BD extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "location.db";
   public static final String LOCATION_TABLE_NAME = "cadastro";
   public static final String CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL = "nomeLocal";
   public static final String CADASTRO_COLUMN_LATITUDE = "latitude";
   public static final String CADASTRO_COLUMN_LONGITUDE = "longitude";

public BD(Context context) {

      super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     db.execSQL(
              "create table " + LOCATION_TABLE_NAME + 
              "(" +
                CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL + " text primary key, " +
                CADASTRO_COLUMN_LATITUDE + " text,"+
                CADASTRO_COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " text" +
              ")"
              );

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "drop table if exists "+ LOCATION_TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
}


   @Override
public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "drop table if exists "+ LOCATION_TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insert (String nome, String latitude, String longitude)
   {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

      contentValues.put(CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL, nome);
      contentValues.put(CADASTRO_COLUMN_LATITUDE, latitude);
      contentValues.put(CADASTRO_COLUMN_LONGITUDE, longitude);  


      db.insert(LOCATION_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
      return true;
   }

   public Cursor consult(int latiude, int longitude){
          SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            String query = "select * from " + LOCATION_TABLE_NAME + " where " + CADASTRO_COLUMN_LATITUDE + " = " + latiude + " AND "+ CADASTRO_COLUMN_LONGITUDE + " = " +longitude;
            Cursor registro = db.rawQuery(query, null); //objeto do sqllite que representa um objeto de qualquer tabela
            return registro;
       }
```

}

**Ocorre o erro quando executo essa linha**

```
 String aux = seleciona.getString(seleciona.getColumnIndex(BD.CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL));
```

**Para apagar a tabela**

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String query = "delete table if exists "+ LOCATION_TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    String queryy = "drop table if exists "+ LOCATION_TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(queryy);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: O erro significa que o `Cursor` está vazio. Ao usar `moveToFirst` o cursor se posiciona uma posição antes da primeira linha, você deve executar um `moveToNext` para consultar (com o `getXYZ`) a primeira e as demais linhas em sequência, verificando se ele não retornou `false` ou verificar usando `isAfterLast`.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Wakim, só tenho um pequeno problema, meu banco não esta sendo excluido quando no onUpgrade, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Comment: A sintaxe do `delete` esta errada, falta o `from`. Além disso ja que esta dropando a tabela, não precisa executar o `delete`.

Comment: Tentei apenas com o drop mas a tabela continua, sendo que para poder colocar um valor novo,quando inicio o app em meu smartphone tenho que ir em configurações -> Aplicativos -> app -> Limpar dados

Comment: Não está dando algum erro? Como está seu `onCreate`, pode incluir na pergunta?

Comment: Pior que não indica nenhum erro. Incluir a classe do banco toda

Comment: Está incrementando a versão sempre que atualiza o schema? Ele só executa o `onUpgrade` quando isso ocorre. Quando você quer apagar o banco? A cada deploy do aplicativo ou a cada abertura?

Comment: De preferência sempre que o app for abert0 (se não for possível pode ser no deploy mesmo)

Answer (score 1):

Quando se está usando o `Cursor`, primeiramente deve usar o `moveToFirst`. Com isso o cursor irá apontar para antes da primeira linha.

Para acessar os dados, use `moveToNext` verificando se o retorno foi `true`. Por exemplo:

```
BD dbm = new BD(getApplicationContext());
Cursor seleciona = dbm.consult(campoLat,campoLong);

seleciona.moveToFirst();

if(seleciona.moveToNext()) {
    String aux = seleciona.getString(seleciona.getColumnIndex(BD.CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL));

    // Restante do código que dependa de aux
}
```

Caso queira iterar sobre os resultados:

```
BD dbm = new BD(getApplicationContext());
Cursor seleciona = dbm.consult(campoLat,campoLong);

seleciona.moveToFirst();

// Eh bom fazer o cache do índice, já que ele nunca muda e evitamos processamento desnecessário
int index = seleciona.getColumnIndex(BD.CADASTRO_COLUMN_NOMELOCAL);

while(seleciona.moveToNext()) {
    String aux = seleciona.getString(index);

    // Restante do codigo que dependa de aux
}
```

No caso do `onUpgrade`, a sintáxe do `delete` está incorreta. O correto seria:

```
delete from nome_tabela
```

Lembrando que o comando [delete](https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#delete-stmt) não suporta `if exists`.

Além disso já que esta dropando a tabela, não é necessário deletar os registros antes.

Edit:

Para limpar o banco na abertura do aplicativo, basta usar a classe `Application`.

Registrando uma classe `Application` você consegue ser notificado do início e o fim da sua aplicação. Com isso pode deletar os registros da tabela.

Basta criar uma subclasse de `android.app.Application` e registrá-la no `AndroidManifest` com o atributo `name`:

```
<application
    android:name="nome.do.seu.pacote.NomeDaApplication">
```

Na sua `NomeDaApplication` basta sobreescrever o método `onCreate` e limpar a tabela:

```
public NomeDaApplication extends android.app.Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Recupera seu banco e apaga os dados
        SQLiteDataBase bd = openOrCreateDatabase("NOME_DO_BANCO", MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        // Usar o bd para apagar as linhas
    }
}
```

**Só tenha um certo cuidado porque não tenho certeza da ordem de execução do `SQLiteOpenHelper` e a execução do `onCreate`. Imagino que poderá dar erro quando o banco é criado pela primeira vez.**

Comment: Obrigado Wakim.