# Dúvida sobre padrão android para comunicar com outras Activitys

Tags: java, android

Tenho uma ActivityMain, ela inicia no começo e só termina sua atividade no fim da aplicação, ou seja enquanto estiver navegando em outras activitys do app essa activity sempre vai estar por trás.
Minha dúvida é, na ActivityMain eu posso possuir um:

> public static ArraiList< ObjetoQualquer > lista;

E em tempo de execução quando estiver navegando em outra activity qualquer do app, eu posso trabalhar com a lista da ActivityMain adicionando itens, ou preenchendo ListView, ou etc?

**exemplo:**

> ActivityMain.lista.add(item)

Isso já testei e funciona. Mas a dúvida é saber se é correto programar dessa forma?
pois, caso eu não fosse fazer isso, eu ia precisar ficar passando o arrayList através de intents, toda vez que chamar uma nova activity.

Comment: O ideal era teres tudo em Base de Dados. E adicionar diretamente a Base de Dados. Essa forma não tem problema, se garantires que a ActivityMain NUNCA termina antes do tempo.

Comment: No meu projeto eu tenho uma base local que guarda apenas os itens do arrayList, e a ActivityMain é a responsável por pegar esses itens e criar um ArrayList com eles, pensei nisso ja, mas não seria custoso toda activity fazer comunicação com o BD?

Comment: Seria mais custoso, mas nada que se note muito (dependendo do tamanho da lista) mas era garantido que não perdia informação. Por isso **depende**, dá importância de não perder dados e da importância de ter a aplicação mais rápida.

Comment: Estou em dúvida se posso implementar dessa forma ou seria gambiarra por não ficar passando por intent.

Comment: Então existe um risco da array não ser encontrada com os dados?

Comment: Existe o risco da sua ActivityMain dar problemas e o array ir a vida.

Comment: Minha sugestão é migrar essa lista para o escopo da instância da Application **sem ser estático**, já que é garantido que ela fica "ativa" enquanto a aplicação estiver rodando. Nessa resposta (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40666/erro-ao-tentar-buscar-dados/40673#40673) eu comento sobre como configurar uma. **Obs: Ainda acho a ideia do @JorgeB. sobre migrar esses dados para o SQLite a melhor, mas isso depende do seu contexto.**